# You have exceeded the maximum limit for Hyperplane ENIs for your account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

Our AWS CodePipeline recently started failing at one of our steps with this error - `You have exceeded the maximum limit for Lambda HyperPlane ENIs for your VPC. Contact AWS support to increase the VPC limit for Lambda HyperPlane ENIs`. We do use a lambda for our load-testing. From [this article I found](https://aws.plainenglish.io/dealing-with-you-have-exceeded-the-maximum-limit-for-hyperplane-enis-for-your-account-223147e7ab64), it seems lambdas run in their own VPC and need an ENI or a HENI (i.e. HyperPlane ENI) to connect to our VPC.

There is a soft limit of 250 HENIs total for the entire VPC in AWS.

How can I fix this issue? There is no mention of ENIs in our IaC code, so maybe they are automatically created for a lambda function? Is there a resource leak?

Comment: Did you read the linked post? It explains in quite some detail how (H)ENIs are used by Lambda, nowhere do they actually create them themselves, they are used under the hood as soon as you deploy lambdas into VPCs. You are lacking all these details: how many lambdas, in how many VPCs, with how many security groups? Have you run the script from the article, have you contacted AWS support?

Answer (score -1):

Although you do not explicitly create an ENI for lambda it is still created to allow your lambda to use the network.

Check this blog post about it: https://aws.plainenglish.io/dealing-with-you-have-exceeded-the-maximum-limit-for-hyperplane-enis-for-your-account-223147e7ab64

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).